# how would I randomise object in geo nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, smoke-simulation, fire, random

Ive made a scene with multiple poles lit on fire but I can't figure out a way to use geo nodes to randomise the fire so it is different on each pole. I would think there is a way to use geo nodes but I'm not sure.[image]

Comment: Hello and welcome to Blender.SE! Try to enable *Separate Children* and *Pick Instance*.